# Reveal my friend's reaction

Tags: knowledge

I recently messaged a video to my friend. It was one of those random, funny YouTube kinds. However, when I asked them what their thoughts were, they sent me a cryptic text back.

> Osmium, Sodium, Polonium, Tungsten, Oxygen, Rhenium, Hydrogen.

I quickly figured it out. What was their reaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elementary! (joke answer)

> Os Na Po W O Re H -> O Snap! Ow or eh? This means: Goodness! Do you think that is painful (ow) or confusing (eh)?